# What can someone do with (non-admin) command prompt on a network?

Tags: network, windows, windows-10, windows-permissions

Say that an organization has a closed network - only its own computers can access it. Each of these computers has Windows 10 Enterprise. For obvious reasons, users aren't given administrator privileges. Anyone within the organization can easily get physical access to one of these devices. The organization is large enough (think university or big corporation) that users shouldn't be trusted.

What are the advantages of blocking `cmd.exe`? That is, what could a user do (bypassing filters, infecting other devices, installing unapproved software, etc.) from a non-elevated Command Prompt that they couldn't do without it?

No network is completely secure, especially if the potential hackers have physical access, but I want to know how much of a difference Command Prompt would make.

I assume that PowerShell and third-party programs like Git Bash would be about the same security-wise, but if there are significant differences, those would be helpful to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing you can do with `cmd` that you can't do with *any* other program, except run `cmd`. This will actually break some malware that specifically tries to invoke `cmd` without having fallbacks to other shells, but it will also break some legit software that uses functions such as `system` or otherwise spawns `cmd` processes. In general, `cmd` isn't a well-favored target for attack payloads - its scripting language is weak and a hassle to code for, and the much more capable `powershell` can now be expected on basically all Windows installs - but it is still the default shell and therefore some stuff will use it by default. If the attacker already has the ability to run arbitrary code *other* than `cmd`, the presence or absence ability to run `cmd` itself is mostly irrelevant.

If most software is blocked (even stuff that doesn't need admin) - that is, if software is whitelisted rather than blacklisted - then `cmd` might make a difference. It facilitates some moderately tricky things like creating symlinks, hardlinks, and junctions (via its `mklink` built-in), and its scripting language, awful though it is, is better than nothing in the case that `powershell`, WSH (`cscript` or `wscript`), and so on are blocked and so is running arbitrary downloaded, compiled, or remote executables. An attack that wanted to do something like that might fail if the system was sufficiently locked down. However, most of what `cmd` can do is somewhat redundant (and it can't actually do much). Since some other software (such as `explorer`, the Windows graphical shell) would presumably still be available, most basic shell operations (navigating the file system, copying/moving/deleting files, launching programs, setting file metadata, accessing environment variables, etc.) would probably be available without `cmd`, and similarly things like editing files would presumably be available through `notepad` or some other editor. Running command-line programs (such as `reg`, the command-line registry utility) doesn't require `cmd`; they can be invoked (with arbitrary arguments) from within `explorer`.

Answer (score -1):

A user could download mIRC, and execute cmd with admin priviliges through a /dde command, for example.

Comment: mIRC is an Internet Relay Chat program. It can run in user mode. But it has a built in DDE Server, that when initialized runs in SYSTEM. If you know how to start/call this server, you can make an administrator privileged CMD.exe console appear. From then on, you can do whatever you like.

Comment: Would there be a way to block elevated command prompt without blocking it entirely?

Comment: You can't install a service, or launch a process as SYSTEM, without already having elevated permissions at some point. Downloading the mIRC installer doesn't mean you can run it, and if you do run it without Admin privileges, it won't be able to install an elevated server. Also, none of this has anything to do with CMD; you could do it without any shell process being available at all.

Comment: try it yourself. /ddeserver on mIRC

Comment: /dde mIRC command /run "" cmd.exe

Comment: Just to confirm that I'm interpreting that correctly, if a user never had admin privileges, command prompt wouldn't change what they're able to do?

Comment: Leo, if a user couldn't become root/system there wouldn't be any hacking. It's called privilege escalation. Sometimes you migrate to a known process, sometimes you invoke a commandline tool through methods like i described. The privileges on that tool can be tricked, as i've shown.

Comment: Respectfully, @Federico, I don't think you understand what I'm talking about. If you just download the mIRC binary and run it as a non-admin without running any installer, it won't be able to launch anything as SYSTEM. If you download the installer and run it without admin, it won't be able to create a service that runs elevated. This is basic OS security 101 stuff; the ability to run *anything* elevated without an elevated user giving you that ability would be a major security hole. Also, your "answer" still doesn't address the question.

Comment: @CBHacking That is exactly what i thought aswell, untill i tried it and it worked.

Comment: Also I would like to point out that this is a hack i used to use when windows XP was around. Still hasn't been fixed.

Comment: The mIRC installer requires admin privileges, so that's a "problem" by itself for this "answer". Just for you, I went and installed it anyhow. Turning on the DDEserver (which just means "a window in this process listens for inter-process messages" doesn't launch any new processes, as SYSTEM or otherwise. Nor does the command you gave launch a privileged process. If you think it does, go ask another question about how it does that (and be prepared to provide functional repro steps).

Comment: @Federico This answer definitely needs either citation or a PoC/W of some sort.